Problem installing driver: make[1]: *** No rule to make target
I trying to install the Quectel QMI_WWAN driver, but I just get make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/aarch64/Makefile'.  Stop.
The user guide says:
Install QMI_WWAN driver.
carl@carl-OptiPlex-7050:~/quectel/qmi_wwan$ sudo make install
So on my computer, I go to the folder containing the driver and the make file, but I just get errors:
`ttgp@ubuntu:~/Downloads/quectel_lte5g_linux_usb_driver_v1-0-2/Quectel_Linux&Android_QMI_WWAN_Driver_V1.1$ sudo make install
make ARCH=aarch64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.10.104-tegra/build M=/home/ttgp/Downloads/quectel_lte5g_linux_usb_driver_v1-0-2/Quectel_Linux&Android_QMI_WWAN_Driver_V1.1 modules
/bin/sh: 1: Android_QMI_WWAN_Driver_V1.1: not found
make: *** [Makefile:22: default] Error 127
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.104-tegra-ubuntu20.04_aarch64/kernel-5.10'
ttgp@ubuntu:~/Downloads/quectel_lte5g_linux_usb_driver_v1-0-2/Quectel_Linux&Android_QMI_WWAN_Driver_V1.1$ Makefile:712: arch/aarch64/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/aarch64/Makefile'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.104-tegra-ubuntu20.04_aarch64/kernel-5.10'
`
inside the makefile it says:
 install: default cp $(PWD)/qmi_wwan_q.ko /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/kernel/drivers/n\ et/usb/ depmod
What do i need to change? Where is the problem?

You have tagged your question Linux, but you don't mention what hardware you are using. (Judging from the aarch64 part in the error messages, I hazard a guess this is an ARM chip, possibly a Raspberry PI.) It appears this driver does not support the aarch64 (ARM 64 bit) architecture, and thus does not support your hardware.

I using a nvidia jetson nano

You should probably [edit] your question to add that information, since it seems (very) important to your problem.

Never heard of aa NVidia Jetson Nano, but a quick look at the relevant product page and its specs, states "Quad-core ARM". So definitely ARM, possibly 64 bit.

I think the point remains the same: the architecture of the CPU is not supported by this driver, so you can't compile this driver for this hardware.
